# Which files can be replaced in a child theme?

Tags: css, theme-twenty-twelve

I have a website which is using a child theme of Twenty Twelve.
As part of the design process, I had to edit `/twentytwelve/css/ie.css`.

Is it possible to save this file in my child theme, and keep twentytwelve's version as it was by default? This would ensure if Twenty Twelve is ever updated, I won't lose the changes I made to `/twentytwelve/css/ie.css`.

Answer (score 0):

For `ie.css` specifically, the issue is that it is included via [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri), which will output the parent theme directory when a child theme is being used. The solution is to add an action hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts` with a lower priority, [dequeue the stylesheet](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style), then re-enqueue it using [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri), which will load it from the child theme directory.

Comment: How do I add an action hooked to wp_enqueue_scripts with a lower priority?

How do I re-enqueue it using get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?  In what file do I do this?

Comment: see priority argument of [`add_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action). look in twentytwelve `functions.php` for where they enqueue the css file, copy it to your child theme's functions.php, swap get_template_directory_uri for get_stylesheet_directory_uri.

Comment: Thanks.  I now know about the priority argument of add_action, but what do you mean by "add an action hooked to wp_enqueue_scripts with a lower priority?".  What action?  In what file do I do this?